# disable / enable mouseenter and mouseleave on click - jquery

Tags: javascript, function, toggle, jquery

I've tried this:

```
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background','blue');
});
$('#tog').click(function () {
      $('.aaa').off('mouseenter mouseleave').on('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/13/

and it doesn't work - just turns events / functions off.

Also, how can be toggled only one part of the function - for example just `$(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');` - instead of toggling the whole function?

**edit:** [**solution 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/14/) and [**solution 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/15/). solved by Shimon Rachlenko.

Comment: `$('.aaa').off('mouseenter mouseleave').on('mouseenter mouseleave');` What do you expect the last part to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. To what end? Your last line won't do what you think; it will turn off the bound event handlers but the `on` will do nothing because you don't specify a callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some shared variable to flag when to turn off the functionality:

```
var flag = true;
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    if(flag) { // enable this functionality only when flag is set
        $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    if(!flag) return;
    $(this).css('background','blue');
});
$('#tog').click(function () {
    flag = !flag;
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works. can you just show me how can i disable only one part of the function (2nd part of the question).

Comment: Hey Shimon, I have only one more question regarding your code (how to "remember" the chosen preference / set a cookie) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079658/jquery-toggle-function-and-set-a-cookie

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
function mouseenterbk() {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
}

function mouseenter() {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
}

function mouseleave() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
}

$('.aaa').on('mouseenter.bk', mouseenterbk).mouseenter(mouseenter).mouseleave(mouseleave);

//this is a very dump implementation of the click toggle
var flag;
$('#tog').click(function () {
    if (flag) {
        $('.aaa').on('mouseenter.bk', mouseenterbk);
        flag = false;
    } else {
        $('.aaa').off('mouseenter.bk');
        flag = true;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6cqRk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var toggle = false;

 $('#tog').click(function () {
  if(toggle == false){
    $('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
        $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
    });
    $('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
         $(this).css('background','blue');
    });
    toggle = true;
  }
  else{
        $('.aaa').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        toggle = false;
  }
 });
```