# jquery toggle function and set a cookie

Tags: function, cookies, jquery-cookie, jquery

I have the following function which toggles mouseenter and mouseleave on click:

```
var flag = true;
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    if(flag) {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    if(flag) {
    $(this).css('background','blue');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid transparent 1px');
});
$('#tog').click(function () {
    flag = !flag;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/15/

How can chosen preference be "remembered" and loaded on the next page load?

**edit:** in case that the solution from bellow doesn't work on the site for some reason, just put it here:

```
 (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //Scripts go in here!
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme):

```
var storedFlag = $.cookie('userSelection'); // read cookie
var flag = 1;  //default value
if(storedFlag != undefined){   // some flag was stored
    flag = storedFlag;
}
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    if(flag > 0) {
        $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    if(flag > 0) {
        $(this).css('background','blue');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid transparent 1px');
});
$('#tog').click(function () {
    flag = 1 - flag;
    $.cookie('userSelection', flag, { expires: 30 }); // store cookie
});
```

The problem is that the boolean values are stored as strings, and the string 'false' is a true value, thus i resorted to using numbers and `>0` comparison.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/20/)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've tried with the single jquery.cookie.js file and with the whole plugin folder, and I've tried to add your code to the toggle f (same .js file) and I've tried with the separate .js file - nothing works. (toggle f gets disabled in case of the single file). Is there any other way to do this (with or without this plugin)?

Comment: You could AJAX a PHP script to set cookies?

Comment: @GroovyCarrot it is an overkill to use ajax and php just for setting cookies

Comment: fantastic. thank you very much. only thing left is to figure out why suddenly toggle function doesn't work on the site (what that plugin might messed)... caching disabled, deleted history and cookies from browser, deleted plugin files and still nothing...

Comment: Yeah my bad, guess I only just skimmed over the question :)

Comment: my bad, as usual when something like this happens (typo in function). thanks again and best of luck :)

Comment: hey man, just one last piece of the puzzle - how can I wrap if(flag > 0) around $('.aaa').attr('preload','auto', sample.play())? basically, I need this in order to toggle sound play on page load.

Comment: Hey Shimon, if you have time here is the new and final question regarding jquery cookie ("remember" and reset div's style) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092425/remember-divs-style-on-click-set-a-cookie-jquery-and-jquery-cookie-plugin