# "remember" div's style on click (set a cookie) - jquery and jquery cookie plugin

Tags: function, cookies, jquery-cookie, jquery

I have a group of divs with mouseenter, mouseleave and click events.

```
var originalAttributes = $('.aaa').attr('style');
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background','blue');
});
$('.aaa').click(function () {
    var $this =  $(this);
    update_x1(this);
    $this.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
$('#save').click(function () {
    $.cookie({ expires: 30 });
});
$('#clear').click(function () {
    $('.aaa').attr('style',originalAttributes);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/24/

How "save" and "clear" functionality can be achieved in this function and with the usage of jquery cookie plugin?

Click on "save" should "remember" the div's current style, and click on "clear" should reset the style to original and clear the cookie (or re-write).

**edit:** solved by Shimon Rachlenko - [**http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/31/**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/31/)

Comment: You need to save the style of the `.aaa` element?

Comment: yes, all divs with that class.

Comment: These divs may have different styles.

Comment: default style is the same for all divs with .aaa class, but each single div interacts individually with mouse events.

Comment: So, the clear button should reset style to some default style, not the stored style, right? And the save button - whether it should save styles for each div separately or for only one of them if the divs have different styles?

Comment: I guess there is no practical reason to save intact divs, so remembering only changed divs sounds like the best solution (especially because I have a lot of divs).

Comment: and yes, clear should reset style to default.

Comment: You will need id or some other means to distinguish between divs.

Comment: ok, let's say that ids are from b1 to b100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for save and clear buttons:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('.aaa').each(function(){
        var d = $(this),
        id = d.attr('id'),
        style = d.attr('style');
        if (style != originalAttributes){   //style changed
            $.cookie('aaaStyle' + id, style, { expires: 30 });
        }
    });

});
var originalAttributes = "position: relative; left: 50px; top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 50px; background: #222222";
$('#clear').click(function () {
    // unset changes
    $('.aaa').attr('style',originalAttributes);
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/29/)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome, and it doesn't work.

Comment: "save" doesn't seem to work. (also, "clear" should also clear the cookie, or if it's easier, just make these buttons memorize the state of all divs).

Comment: Save creates cookies for each div, named aaaStyleb1. Added remove cookies, see http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/30/

Comment: no results here :( ... when I click on "save" and reload, nothing happens - only default style gets loaded.

Comment: Now I see.. You never mentioned before that you want to reapply the saved styles:) You only said that you want to save styles:)

Comment: :)  Yes, I want to automatically load saved styles after visitor gets back to the page. and "clear" should be also memorized (load default state on the next visit).

Comment: You should have said that from the beginning:) here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/31/

Comment: hey, if you have time I have a question regarding your code - handling large cookies - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118490/handling-large-cookies-jquery-and-jquery-cookie-plugin

Comment: more specific - how this same "save - clear" functionality can be achieved with the local storage?

Comment: Hey Shimon, since your help really meant a lot to me, I would like to repay you in some way (would be useful for both of us) - if you have a site / blog / etc and if you are interested in details, I'm here - x_xs1@yahoo.com