# handling large cookies or using local storage - jquery and jquery cookie plugin

Tags: function, cookies, jquery-cookie, jquery

I have the working code which sets and clears cookie (remembers div's style) on click:

```
var originalAttributes = $('.aaa').attr('style');
$('.aaa').each(function(){
    var d = $(this),
    id = d.attr('id'),
    storedStyle = $.cookie('aaaStyle' + id);
    if (storedStyle != undefined){   //style stored
        d.attr('style', storedStyle);
    }
});

//mouse event functions for class="aaa"

$('#save').click(function () {
    $('.aaa').each(function(){
        var d = $(this),
        id = d.attr('id'),
        style = d.attr('style');
        if (style != originalAttributes){   //style changed
            $.cookie('aaaStyle' + id, style, { expires: 30 });
        }
    });

});

$('#clear').click(function () {
    // unset changes
    $('.aaa').attr('style',originalAttributes).each(function(){
        var d = $(this),
        id = d.attr('id');
        $.cookie('aaaStyle' + id, null);
    });
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/31/**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/31/)

Only problem which occurs with this is when I have to handle a lot of divs of the same class - cookie size can get to 500kb or more. Browsers supports only 4kb per cookie.

So the question is - how can this problem be avoided with this function and with the jquery cookie plugin? - gzip or / and splitting the cookie in small enough parts?

(in either way, it would be good to have some sort of compression in order to speed up the performance (if possible - but if not, doesn't matter))

**edit:** how this same "save - clear" functionality can be achieved with the local storage?

**edit2:** solved by user2111737 ([**http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/33/**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/33/)) - uses local storage instead of cookie and works without cookie plugin.

Comment: I guess you don't need to save that many stuff - save real data, then rebuild markup via any kind of templating language.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. can you please show me (update this fiddle)?

Comment: If your cookies get this large you should look into other options, like localStorage. Remember that, if these cookies are set to *.yourdomain.com, they are attached to every single request, so it's a huge performance (traffic) hit.

Comment: i got it, so I've updated the question. thing is I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need to access it on server side or eventually it's possible to manually send this data to server with xmlhttprequest I think you should rather try localStorage, eventually sessionStorage instead of cookies, then you have 20mb (200 in IE but shared with other sites). About compression - you can think about custom format and rebuild html code using stored data in fly - eg. i doubt this class can be absolutely anything - i guess it could be saved as number - or even better - one character. It gives you 255 classes saved as one sign

Comment: Thing is that I would like to implement an easy "save / clear" solution which would work without profiles and stuff like that, and which would remember visitor's choice for good.

Comment: but localStorage is saved for browser - it doesn't expire at all. I don't know many people who use 3 browsers at once, you don't need profiles or anything save:  localStorage.setItem('variablename', 'value'), clear: localStorage.removeItem('name')

Comment: I got it. Can you please show me how to implement this for my functions (update the fiddle)? I'm totally new in this.

Comment: you mean $.cookie should be replaced with $.localStorage.setItem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/32/

I'm not sure if $ is the same as window but probably not, I'm not using jQ so i don't know. I guess it works as you expected

Comment: thanks a lot! this does work in fiddle and without cookie plugin, so I guess you did your part. I just need to test it on the site - hopefully it will show well.

Comment: just to confirm that this works flawlessly. thank you very much again.

Comment: just one more question - can the data sent to the local storage be compressed? (new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124425/localstorage-compression-jquery)