# localStorage compression? - jquery

Tags: function, compression, local-storage, jquery

I have the function which saves and clears div's style to localStorage on click:

```
var originalAttributes = $('.aaa').attr('style');
$('.aaa').each(function(){
    var d = $(this),
    id = d.attr('id'),
    storedStyle = window.localStorage.getItem('aaaStyle' + id);
    if (storedStyle != undefined){   //style stored
        d.attr('style', storedStyle);
    }
});

//mouse event functions for class="aaa"

$('#save').click(function () {
    $('.aaa').each(function(){
        var d = $(this),
        id = d.attr('id'),
        style = d.attr('style');
        if (style != originalAttributes){   //style changed
            //$.cookie('aaaStyle' + id, style, { expires: 30 });
            window.localStorage.setItem('aaaStyle' + id, style);
        }
    });

});

$('#clear').click(function () {
    // unset changes
    $('.aaa').attr('style',originalAttributes).each(function(){
        var d = $(this),
        id = d.attr('id');
        window.localStorage.removeItem('aaaStyle' + id);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/33/

What should be added to this code so that data in the local storage gets compressed?

(there is memory limit per domain in each browser and I would like to maximize this functionality)

Comment: The limit is 5MB as far as I know. That is hell of a lot. Does your application require more?

Comment: I have multiple pages and each requires up to 1MB.

Comment: Didn't some versions of Chrome have 2.5mb, but that's still a hell of a lot, something like 2 560 000 characters ?

Comment: Additional compression on one million character texts per page will introduce CPU consumption. I am not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: maybe you are right, but I am still interested to see this in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compress string in webworker to not put unnecessary load on primary thread - there are libraries for strings compression, even lzma, as far as i know localStorage allows to allocate up to 20mb in modern browsers per page and 200 mb in IE shared through all sites - additional compression - you can build map of ids and classes if there is less than 255 ids and classes and save them as one character using String.fromCharCode(int) and save as one big string in localStorage then to decode - inputstr[pos].charCodeAt(0) for every pair to convert to usable object at page startup. However then it's bad idea to generate this big string on every change and i'd use onbeforeunload event to do this before page is closed

Comment: actually i need to do this for my own website, so if you want i'll post tomorrow jsfiddle for that (sorry that not now)

Comment: ok, thanks. I appreciate it, since I am a total newbie in this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nhRcD/ it shows basic idea, I wasn't sure how do theese style rules look like

Comment: 1. yes, I am a total novice :)  2. if I understood correctly, I need to add classes on the list, then to put this code in .js file - let's say comp.js - and then to call it in click function by putting window.SDget('aaaStyle' + id, style) right bellow window.localStorage.setItem('aaaStyle' + id, style); ? (it would probably be the best that you show me in fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/33/).

Comment: if you're able to use classes instead of style attribute - then it's ready to use code - nearly: `window.SDget(id)` returns class name, `window.SDput(id,class)` saves new state - just under it you can call window.SDstore()` (i explained why i commented it) to save data in storage.

Comment: you mean that `window.SDget('aaaStyle' + id, style)` should go with or instead of `window.localStorage.getItem('aaaStyle' + id, style)` in the same function? also `window.SDput('aaaStyle' + id, style)` and `window.SDstore('aaaStyle' + id, style)` together with / instead `window.localStorage.setItem('aaaStyle' + id, style)` ?

Comment: I've tried this - http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/35/ - and whatever I try with that function from your fiddle it doesn't work at all (mouse events gets nonfunctional).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/37/ yeah, it wasn't tested at all now should work, at least theese functions work properly and classes are saved / get properly - i guess jsfiddle may have some troubles with localStorage, that's why it seems to not work. Generally I'm not sure if using style property was intended but if not you should use classes for this. It's even possible to edit css loaded by browser in fly to modify whole class at once

Comment: is this reorganized structure with css styling and classes necessary? because I got to stick with my current structure. also, I see that your code is dependent to ids rather than classes. Does it have to be like that? - I should avoid listing ids since I have them a lot more than 255 (which is why I need compressing in the 1st place).

Comment: well if there is more than 255 ids... um could you explain why do you need so many elements? I mean it's A LOT of html elements and I'm not sure it'll achieve enough performance. If you're trying to draw something it's not good idea to use html for that
if you're using N ids and M style records and there is more than 255 of both of them, then you need do split it but it's more work

Comment: I use divs because I need both bg color and border to be interactive for each individually. And I also have some jquery functions for them. And on top of all of that - every div's style should be remembered individually by clicking on "save". I don't know how can this be achieved in a better way than having divs in html.

Comment: if I really have to split divs in groups up to 255 because of compression - I should definitely drop it. I'm happy how local storage works right now. Only thing which worries me is what happens when visitor clicks "save" on several pages (aka exceeds browser's per domain limit).

Comment: bg color and border can be achieved using 2 classes per div instead of one, but why that many divs. You could build whatever you're going to using canvas (if it's graphics related, then you can remember colors and position in JS object, you can build svg, or build html, it depends what you want to achieve - canvas will be fastest - html easiest to deal with events but slowest. all of theese methods can be at final step compressed like in given code. it depends mostly on number of theese divs - 10k divs is starting to be trouble for browsers when content is more dynamic.

Comment: you can save color of border and bg as set of chars: `irgbrgb` - for more ids - `iirgbrgb` - then you have 256^256 divs and 2 colors - 8 chars per div

Comment: generally operating on html in this way is slow - i'd use array of html elements instead of ids and compare pointer with array, or at least save id in other property than id, eventually 2d binary search... there is plenty of completly different ways, id can put some unnecessary computing as browser may look for id in css.

Comment: ok, this should probably be a lot more optimized, but that would be too advanced for me + I probably don't have time for that. btw only slowdown is in Firefox (but not so bad), so I will stick with html (at least for now). so, if I have 5k divs and if they have 8 different background colors and 2 different border colors, is there any way to compress saved data without splitting and without changing the html? (I should ask this question right away, I thought that 1MB data is good enough info).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/47/ here. I hope It works as you wish. I'm not sure what is highest limit but rather number of unicode characters, ofc you'll generate theese ids as you want, i just put example with 5000 ids and 16 classes.

Comment: and i'd recommend you to learn clear js - seriously, maybe it looks little tiny more complex but in fact it's not true - it's way simplier, you have good syntax hinting in Chrome js console, it's faster, more universal etc etc

Comment: ofc 16 classes for every combination you need - it's exactly what you're going to achieve i guess

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help. only "clear" is incomplete - divs are not back to default after reload - but maybe that's not so bad. only thing left is to test it on the site with multiple saves, if more than 5 pages can be saved, than it definitely works.

Comment: because i forgot to plug it - add `SDreset(id)` for each id on reset click ;)

Comment: and yeah - maybe noobish question - will this work with my code structure (without css and with my function for multiple clicks)? btw, I will not manage to finish pages any time soon, and I actually have more variations on some pages than 8 + 2 colors (and on some less).

Comment: and regarding this part: `SDget('b1'), SDget('b2')` is there a better way than listing few thousands ids individually?

Comment: i'd recommend to use classes as it's easier to manage. in theory you could add instead of classes - various style contents, but it may be bad idea. I've put here function to swap last class in div instead of changing style so theese are most important changes. (btw. there was serious bug in removing http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/51/ this one works)

Comment: <<< _is there a better way than listing few thousands ids individually_
generally SDget uses map to navigate to proper char in string - you could speed it up for initial load by taking SDget content out of function - because in this case function call will put more noticeable cpu load than its content itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/53/ there is absolutely fastest initial asign (i put your old code in comment). For changes where not all of divs are changed SDget should be fast enough - and generally now slowest point is html rendering by browser

Comment: thanks a lot again for the code. maybe I'm not in situation to implement it now, but it can definitely be useful for future projects. right now, instead of compression, maybe I should implement some kind of alert / confirm system which would pop up when something old (previously saved page) in the local storage is about to get overwritten with new. I might post another question regarding this when I finish and test these pages.

Comment: Hey, since your help really meant a lot to me, I would like to repay you in some way. I have one simple idea - one-sided (on me), but beneficial for the both of us - if you have a site / blog / anything and if you are interested in details, I'm here - x_xs1@yahoo.com