# Is there any way to reduce the size of a list of strings loaded in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, typeahead

Okay, so I want to load a [2.5MB json file](http://www.opentaal.org/bestanden) in a browser, so I can do some typeAhead functions with it.

However, my localstorage seems to be always full. In Firefox I get this error in the console:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED: Persistent storage maximum size reached @ http://localhost/www/js/twitter-typeahead.js:223
```

In chrome, there is no error in the console, but the tab that hosts my app has a continuous cpu hog of 25%.

Is there anything I can do about this? How can I load all the strings from the jsonfile into local storage without hogging the browser or completely filling the localstorage?

I can create smaller json files but in the end I still need to have all the data loaded at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [localStorage compression? - jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124425/localstorage-compression-jquery)

Comment: Maybe use WebWorkers to load your JSON file and return an array for your typeahead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a library like this to compress it: http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Comment: Well, I can't say it doesn't do it's job, but it takes 8.3 seconds to compress my data.. That's a long time for a mobile app :( I guess I have to make the hard descission choose between functionality and performance.. Thx for the tip though!

Comment: Is there a PHP library compatible with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : https://github.com/k-yak/JJLC

It compress JSON file in your localStorage creating hashmaps, you can save betwenn 30% - 50% of total size.

demo : http://k-yak.github.io/JJLC/